# how to convert one double Array to an another double Array (empty)

Tags: c#, arrays, json, ienumerable

I have a string which is

> 35.318073;65.741196;57.335339;87.758453;+0.573;;42.282722;92.314201;64.299988;114.331459;+0.537;;89.842690;109.230721;111.859947;131.247986;+0.644;;

I am using the below code to split it and then convert it into a JSON object and then convert it into a double object.

```
if (readByCount > 30)
                {

                    var output = (new string(buff).TrimEnd('\u0000'));
                    Console.WriteLine(output);

                    var output1 = output.Split(new[] { ";;" },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s.Split(';')).ToArray();

                    JToken jsonParsed = JToken.FromObject(output1);

                    List<double> zcoordinate = new List<double>();
                    double zaxis = 0.0;
                    double[] MediumArray = { 0,0 };
                    double zCoordinateMin = 0.0;



                    foreach (var arrayItem in jsonParsed)
                    {
                        var innerArray = arrayItem.ToObject<double[]>();
                        MediumArray.Append<double[]>(innerArray);

                        zaxis = innerArray.ElementAt<double>(4);
                        zcoordinate.Add(zaxis);
                        foreach (var item in zcoordinate)
                        {
                            zCoordinateMin = zcoordinate.Min();
                        }
                    }


                    for (int i = 0; i < MediumArray.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (MediumArray.ElementAt(i) == zCoordinateMin)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(MediumArray[0] + MediumArray[1]);
                        }


}
```

As you can see, because of the format of the input string, the for-each loop will run thrice. I want to make my MediumArray an Array of an array so that I can run the foreach loop to find the MediumArray[0] + MediumArray[1] only for that array which has the least value of element which is at position 5 (index 4).

I know if I have the mediumArray an array of an array, I cant use a for loop shown in my code but I have to use a for-each loop something like:

```
//foreach (var item in MediumArray)
                        //{


                        //    if (MediumArray.ElementAt(4) == zCoordinateMin)
                        //    {
                        //        Console.WriteLine(MediumArray[0] + MediumArray[1]);
                        //    }
                        //}
```

I am trying this code, but I am getting an error because of this line.

```
MediumArray.Append<double[]>(innerArray);
```

The error says:

> 'double[]' does not contain a definition for 'Append' and the best
>   extension method overload
>   'Enumerable.Append(IEnumerable, double[])'
>   requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable'

What can I do to execute the process correctly?

Comment: MediumArray.Append(innerArray).ToArray() or just keep it as IEnumerable - MediumArray.Append(innerArray)

Comment: its simple don't use an array, use a list or something that has append.

Comment: @pwrigshihanomoronimo MediumArray.Apeend(innerArray).ToArray() doesnt work. it gives the same error.

Comment: @MichaelRandall. Thanks. I solved it by making a List of double[]. and running for each loop on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Linq query I came up with that does the job:

```
var input = "35.318073;65.741196;57.335339;87.758453;+0.573;;42.282722;92.314201;64.299988;114.331459;+0.537;;89.842690;109.230721;111.859947;131.247986;+0.644;;";

var output = input
  .Split(";;")                                    // split input string into the double arrays
  .Where(array => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(array))   // ignore empty array (last one in your example)
  .Select(array => array                          
    .Split(";")                                   // split into single values
    .Select(value => double.Parse(value))         // parse them to doubles
    .ToArray())                                   // join them together as an array
  .ToArray();                                     // join the arrays together as an array
```

This query returns a `System.Double[][]`.

Comment: Split(";;") doesn't work, says the error, cant convert from string to char. Thanks though. I solved it by using another method

Comment: @VedantGonnade I tested the code on https://repl.it/languages/csharp and it ran without any error